# Compound Predicate with two Prepositional Phrases / Preposition Deletion

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, subjects, compound-sentences, compound-subjects

My intention is to say that:

- (A) I will be **traveling** on Mon & Tue. I will be **eating** on Mon & Tue.

Is this a correct paraphrase -?->

- (B) I will be traveling **and** eating on Mon **and** Tue.

Or does the sentence (B) instead mean -?->

- (C) I will be traveling. I will be eating on Mon & Tue.

Comment: Well, juxtaposition of those two verbs is somewhat odd.

Comment: @Lambie How can I fix it?

Comment: I will be singing and dancing on Monday and Tuesday.

Comment: But that's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: But will you be breathing?

Comment: @Lambie Or, you mean: because singing and dancing are similar activities - that's why it's an acceptable sentence.

Comment: @Xanne Sorry, but I didn't understand.

Comment: One would assume that you eat every day, whether travelling or not! But if you want to clarify that you plan two activities on each of two days, you could say _on both Monday and Tuesday_

Comment: (B) could mean either A or C; it's a famous ambiguity. (B') 'I will be traveling, and eating on Mon and Tuesday' clearly means (C), but there's no such simple way of forcing meaning (A). (A') 'I will be both traveling and eating on both Monday and Tuesday' works, but is worse than the original. Quit while you're not too far behind. // Note that (A'') 'I will be both traveling and eating on Monday and Tuesday' does not resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Look, this is almost not an English questions, really.

Comment: @Lambie I can't find the original, but the best answer was deservedly well-upvoted. This ambiguity does need addressing (once).

Answer (score 1):

> <s>B) I will be traveling and eating on Mon**day** and Tue**sday**.</s>

The construction that you want is:

On Mon**day** and Tue**sday**, I will be traveling and eating.

A fronting adverbial is a free modifier and modifies the entire clause (or clauses where there is more than one equal clause.)

Comment: This is what struck my mind too.